# Oracle SQL query Alternative to using Condition 'value1 is NULL OR Value1 =Value2'

Tags: oracle

I am querying from 2 tables, template_table(Columns: ID, Market, Currency) & Value_table(Columns:ID, Market, Currency, x, y, z)

I only want to use the the rows from Value_table if they match to the template_table using ID field and only use the Market & Currency to match if they are not null in the template_table:

example data in template table could look like:

| ID | MARKET | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | IRE | EUR |
| 7 | (null) | USD |
| 7 | FRA | (null) |

Template table can have many rows per template.ID.
The table is relatively small in volume, but for some reason Oracle performs slow for me.  I have added INDEX on the ID Column in the TEMPLATE_TABLE but there wasn't much improvement

SELECT * FROM
VALUE_TABLE T1

JOIN TEMPLATE_TABLE T2 ON  T1.ID = T2.ID

AND (T1.MARKET is Null or T1.MARKET= T2.MARKET)
AND (T1.CURRENCY is Null or T1.CURRENCY = T2.CURRENCY)

WHERE T1.ID = 7

Could there be a better way to write this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   VALUE_TABLE T1
       JOIN TEMPLATE_TABLE T2
       ON (   T1.ID = T2.ID
          AND T2.market = COALESCE( T1.market, T2.market )
          AND T2.currency = COALESCE( T1.currency, T2.currency )
          )
WHERE  T1.ID = 7
```

But I think that is more difficult to read (and you would need to check whether Oracle makes use of indexes using that method) and I think would be easier to use your original method:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   VALUE_TABLE T1
       JOIN TEMPLATE_TABLE T2
       ON (   T1.ID = T2.ID
          AND (T1.MARKET is Null or T1.MARKET= T2.MARKET)
          AND (T1.CURRENCY is Null or T1.CURRENCY = T2.CURRENCY)
          )
WHERE T1.ID = 7
```

Comment: Thanks MTO.  I tried out your suggestion on the COALESCE, it seems to give me the same performance however I need to review explain plan to see what Oracle is using.   I only have an INDEX on the ID column on the *template* table, the other table is actually a Global Temp table with no INDEXES.. so maybe this is something I need to update